# Nested sub-items in a dropdown overlapping with main items

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to solve an issue in the checkout page in Woocommerce.

When the user tries to choose a parcel machine the dropdown arranges the choices by region and under each shows the corresponding options.

But the sub-items are overlapping with the main region options:
[IMAGE: overlapping nested elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sdrA.png)

The issue can be seen live here: https://kvest.ee/en/checkout/ When something has been added to cart beforehand.

I have tried setting relative positions and inline-block to various elements, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Before you ask something like this the next time, please go read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove (or increase) the height in your css for your select class.

This code, remove the Height.

```
.select2-container .select2-dropdown .select2-results .select2-results__option {
  margin: 0;
  height: 40px; ***<-remove or increase this.***
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

With the height removed, that's how it looks for me.
[image]
[image]

Comment: oh heck. Thank you ever so much. That indeed did solve it.